# How i can use ioctl for the communication between the user program and driver?

Tags: c, module, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

i am writing a driver in linux. How i can use ioctl for the communication between the user program and driver  ?
In my driver, the structure is as follows:

```
struct file_operations fops = {.read = device_read,.write = device_write,.unlocked_ioctl = device_ioctl,.open = device_open,.release=device_release };
```

In my understanding, here the device_ioctl is a function that handles the ioctl call from the user program. And call can be possible with variable number of parameters.

But i am not sure about the way of using ioctl. Also totally confused and eager to know that how i can write device_ioctl ?

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First you should learn how `ioctl` is used from user-space, then check how similar drivers implement it, then figure out what your driver need.

Comment: can you suggest some reference?.

Answer (score 2):

I believe [LDD3](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/) chapter 6.1 can answer your question with good examples.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `register_chrdev` to get a major number for your kernel file. Give `fops` as a parameter.
2. You get a major number returned (you can also find it in `/proc/devices`) use this number with the `mknod` command to create `/dev/yourdevice`.
3. In your user space code, open `/dev/yourdevice` and use the `ioctl` function with the file descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any `proc` file instead of the device in a such way:

```
static long my_proc_ioctl(struct file * file, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg)
{
    printk("%s() cmd=%.08x arg=%pK\n", __func__, cmd, (void *)arg);
    return 0;
}

static const struct file_operations my_ioctl_fops = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .unlocked_ioctl = my_proc_ioctl,
};

[...]
proc_create("my_ioctl_file", 0600, NULL, &my_ioctl_fops);
[...]
```